# How to put the sum of two numbers beside the " = "

Tags: java, loops

I want to display the sum of two numbers beside the equal sign.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         int i ;
            System.out.println("enter a number: " );
            i = scan.nextInt();
            int a = i - 1  ; 
            while(a >= 1){
                System.out.println(i +" + "+ a + " = " );

//i want to display the sum of two numbers beside the equal sign.

               i =i + a ;
                System.out.println(i);
                a --;


//  how can I display the answer beside the equal sign?

            }
      } 
    }
```

How can I display the answer beside the equal sign?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow! Can you please adjust your formatting so that the code block is more readable? Also, can you please provide an example of actual output and desired one?

Answer (score 1):

Change your first `println` to `print`.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question I think you are most probably asking how we can show the sum of two numbers in the print statement.
So in your code after "=" you just need to add (i+a) this will sum the value of i and a. 
`System.out.println(i +" + "+ a + " = " + (i+a))`.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println()` method prints a *"newline character"* (**\n**) right after its' input.

There is another method that does not do this:

`System.out.print()`

You should **change**

`System.out.println(i +" + "+ a + " = " );`  to

`System.out.print(i +" + "+ a + " = " );` this.